# PyQt5 - Can't play video using QVideoWidget

Tags: python, linux, gstreamer, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QVideoWidget()
w.resize(300, 300)
w.move(0, 0)
w.show()

player = QMediaPlayer()
player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("/home/doflamingo    /Documents/Nisemono/got.avi")))
player.setVideoOutput(w)

player.play()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This very simple code give the following output on ArchLinux :

```
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:///home/doflamingo/Documents/Nisemono/got.avi"
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:///home/doflamingo/Documents/Nisemono/got.avi"
```

Everything seems up-to-date and the codecs for GStreamer are installed.

Comment: I tested this on arch-linux and it works fine for me. Are you sure the file-path is correct and the avi file is playable?

Comment: connect to the player's error handler, and see what you can learn about the error. `player.error.connect(handleError)`, then inspect what gets passed into your `handleError` slot via it's first positional argument, and reference the QMediaPlayer.Error enum

Comment: Your question has helped me a lot. I couldnt figure out how to add a video widget to a Qt designer ui and your example code gave me a clue. Cheers