# pyqt5 videowidget not showing in layout

Tags: pyqt5

I am writing a program with `pyqt5` where pressing a button first cycles through some pictures then cycles through some videos.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
import glob
import argparse

import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,args):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Navon test')
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        # exit option for the menu bar File menu
        self.exit = QAction('Exit', self)
        self.exit.setShortcut('Ctrl+q')
        # message for the status bar if mouse is over Exit
        self.exit.setStatusTip('Exit program')
        # newer connect style (PySide/PyQT 4.5 and higher)
        self.exit.triggered.connect(app.quit)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.ico'))
        self.centralwidget = CentralWidget(args)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    def keyPressEvent(self, QKeyEvent):
        if QKeyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            QCoreApplication.instance().quit()
        self.centralwidget.startvid()

class CentralWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,args):
        super(CentralWidget, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.player = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.vw = QVideoWidget()
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.vw)

    def startvid(self):
        self.layout.addWidget(self.vw)
        url= QUrl.fromLocalFile(glob.glob("videos/*")[0])
        content= QMediaContent(url)
        self.player.setMedia(content)
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.vw)
        self.player.play()
if __name__== "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    #~ parser.add_argument("-nb","--nobox",action="store_true", help="do not wait for the box connection")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainWindow(args)
    #~ mainwindow.showFullScreen()
    mainwindow.show()


    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried to paste the minimal code. The thing is, I press the button nothing shows, although I used examples like this one [PyQt5 - Can't play video using QVideoWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170552/pyqt5-cant-play-video-using-qvideowidget) to test if playing the video is ok, and these work. It's as if it is not adding the widget to the layout or something. Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use QGraphicsView to achieve what I wanted, here is a fix:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
import glob
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Navon test')
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        # exit option for the menu bar File menu
        self.exit = QAction('Exit', self)
        self.exit.setShortcut('Ctrl+q')
        # message for the status bar if mouse is over Exit
        self.exit.setStatusTip('Exit program')
        # newer connect style (PySide/PyQT 4.5 and higher)
        self.exit.triggered.connect(app.quit)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.ico'))
        self.centralwidget = VideoPlayer()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    def keyPressEvent(self, QKeyEvent):
        if QKeyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.centralwidget.phaseQuit(2)
        self.centralwidget.play()

class VideoPlayer(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.videoItem = QGraphicsVideoItem()
        self.videoItem.setSize(QSizeF(640, 480))
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        graphicsView = QGraphicsView(scene)
        scene.addItem(self.videoItem)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(graphicsView)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoItem)
        self.counter = 0




    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            pass
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(glob.glob("videos/*")[self.counter])))
            self.mediaPlayer.play()
            self.counter += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = MainWindow()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```